# CorePlot - Pad Labels near edge of plot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I'm using automatic labeling (CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic) with the CPTCalendarFormatter formatter to format my x axis - so far so good.

However, my graph is full width in it's container and because of that, the 2 labels at the edges of the plot are being clipped. See below:

[image]

Is there a simple way to format the padding on the first and last label, so that they sit within the graph, rather than extending beyond it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the labels to fit under the graph, (not extend beyond the edges of the graph).

As I see it you have two options:

1. Expand plot range as others have mentioned before, or
2. Define the positions of your labels yourself.

Example of how to set your own label positions:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet; //your graph's axis set;
NSSet *labelPositions; //some set containing positions of all labels stored as NSNumbers

[axisSet.xAxis setLabelingPolicy:CPTAxisLabelingPolicyLocationsProvided];
[axisSet.xAxis setMajorTickLocations:labelPositions];
```

Comment: Great, setting the labelPositions manually did the trick (I set the first and last slightly off the round number, ie 1.0 -> 1.1). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set some padding on the plot area frame to leave room for the labels:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft  = 20.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 20.0;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need to keep the graph itself full-width. This also pads the graph, unless I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The labels cannot extend outside the hosting view. The alternative is to expand the plot range slightly to move the labeled points in from the edges.